# Saying northeast, northwest, north-north-east, etc

Tags: words, direction

What would the correct way to write and say northeast, northwest, north-north-east, etc?

In Chinese, we put east and west first and then put north or south at the end, for example, 東北 for northeast.
Is this the same in Japanese? And would the Japanese pronunciation be とうほく, ひがしきた or something else?
Also, how would one write or say directions such as north-north-east or south-west-south (ie. Cardinal directions with three parts)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a list of compass directions on [wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BE%85%E9%87%9D%E6%96%B9%E4%BD%8D):

> 1  北   N   トラモンターナ (en)        0.00°   5.62°
>   2  北微東 NbE Qto Tramontana verso Greco  5.63°   11.25°  16.87°
>   3  北北東 NNE Greco-Tramontana    16.88°  22.50°  28.12°
>   4  北東微北    NEbN    Qto Greco verso Tramontana  28.13°  33.75°  39.37°
>   5  北東  NE  グレコ (en)    39.38°  45.00°  50.62°
>   6  北東微東    NEbE    Qto Greco verso Levante 50.63°  56.25°  61.87°
>   7  東北東 ENE Greco-Levante   61.88°  67.50°  73.12°
>   8  東微北 EbN Qto Levante verso Greco 73.13°  78.75°  84.37°
>   9  東   E   レバンテ (en)   84.38°  90.00°  95.62°
>   10 東微南 EbS Qto Levante verso Scirocco  95.63°  101.25° 106.87°
>   11 東南東 ESE Levante-Scirocco    106.88° 112.50° 118.12°
>   12 南東微東    SEbE    Qto Scirocco verso Levante  118.13° 123.75° 129.37°
>   13 南東  SE  シロッコ    129.38° 135.00° 140.62°
>   14 南東微南    SEbS    Qto Scirocco verso Ostro    140.63° 146.25° 151.87°
>   15 南南東 SSE Ostro-Scirocco  151.88° 157.50° 163.12°
>   16 南微東 SbE Qto Ostro verso Scirocco    163.13° 168.75° 174.37°
>   17 南   S   オストロ (en)   174.38° 180.00° 185.62°
>   18 南微西 SbW Qto Ostro verso Libeccio    185.63° 191.25° 196.87°
>   19 南南西 SSW Ostro-Libeccio  196.88° 202.50° 208.12°
>   20 南西微南    SWbS    Qto Libeccio verso Ostro    208.13° 213.75° 219.37°
>   21 南西  SW  リベッチオ (en)  219.38° 225.00° 230.62°
>   22 南西微西    SWbW    Qto Libeccio verso Ponente  230.63° 236.25° 241.87°
>   23 西南西 WSW Ponente-Libeccio    241.88° 247.50° 253.12°
>   24 西微南 WbS Qto Ponente verso Libeccio  253.13° 258.75° 264.37°
>   25 西   W   ポネンテ (en)   264.38° 270.00° 275.62°
>   26 西微北 WbN Qto Ponente verso Maestro   275.63° 281.25° 286.87°
>   27 西北西 WNW Maestro-Ponente 286.88° 292.50° 298.12°
>   28 北西微西    NWbW    Qto Maestro verso Ponente   298.13° 303.75° 309.37°
>   29 北西  NW  マエストロ   309.38° 315.00° 320.62°
>   30 北西微北    NWbN    Qto Maestro verso Tramontana    320.63° 326.25° 331.87°
>   31 北北西 NNW Maestro-Tramontana  331.88° 337.50° 343.12°
>   32 北微西 NbW Qto Tramontana verso Maestro    343.13° 348.75° 354.37°
>   1  北   N   トラモンターナ (en)    354.38° 360.00°

And a sample of readings [here](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1354671953):

> ① 北微西 … ほくびせい
>   ② 北微東 … ほくびとう
>   ③ 北西微北 … ほくせいびほく
>   ④ 北東微北 … ほくとうびほく
>   ⑤ 北西微西 … ほくせいびせい
>   ⑥ 北東微東 … ほくとうびとう
>   ⑦ 西微北 … せいびほく
>   ⑧ 東微北 … とうびほく
>   ⑨ 西微南 … せいびなん
>   ⑩ 東微南 … とうびなん
>   ⑪ 南西微西 … なんせいびせい
>   ⑫ 南東微東 … なんとうびとう
>   ⑬ 南西微南 … なんせいびなん
>   ⑭ 南東微南 … なんとうびなん
>   ⑮ 南微西 … なんびせい
>   ⑯ 南微東 … なんびとう

Comment: While your links answer the OP's question, links die, the contents change. When possible it would be great if you could post a more informative answer. It would also help the site SEO, as the questions/answers are picked up by google, etc.